# Refresh Popup Window

Tags: javascript, json, dajaxice

I am making a website using Django and I want a popup window that displays logging messages and will automatically refresh every N seconds.  I am using the standard python logger, javascript, and Dajaxice for my popups.

I am stuck on how to get the popup to refresh automatically, and it needs to use the log file content retrieved in the Dajaxice function.

**My ajax.py looks like this:**

```
import json, SIMPLCode, logging, os, sys
from dajaxice.decorators import dajaxice_register

@dajaxice_register(method='GET')
def getLogs(request):
  fname = "SIMPLCode/Logs/LOG_2015-07-08.log"
  with open(fname,"r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
  lines = lines[-10:]
  return json.dumps({'logLines':lines})
```

**My proposed Django HTML looks like this**:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Dajaxice.InterfaceApp.getLogs(popitup())">{% bootstrap_icon "share-alt" %} View Log File </button>
```

**The proposed JS looks like this**:

```
function popitup(data) {
    $(document).ready(function(data) {
      var log_file = data.logLines;
      var newwindow=window.open('','Log Viewer','height=300,width=500');
      newwindow.write(log_file)
    });

    if(newwindow && !newwindow.closed){
      newwindow.location.reload(true); 
      newwindow.focus();
    } 
  }
```

I tried this but am getting an error that the data from my dajaxice function is not defined:

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'logLines' of undefined*

Yet when I call it like this (as a simple alert window) it works:

```
<input id="LogMessages" type="button" value="View Log Messages" onclick="Dajaxice.InterfaceApp.getLogs(function(d){alert(d.message);})"/>
```

I am pretty new to JS and dajaxice and there isn't much available online for dajax.  Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in how I was calling it.  The correct way looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="Dajaxice.InterfaceApp.getLogs(popitup)">{% bootstrap_icon "share-alt" %} View Log File </button>
```

There shouldn't have been `()` behind the call to `popitup`